How do I build a nextjs application?
on running the command npm run build to create an optimized production model for my nextjs project, the build folder is not being created or it is not under the .next folder?
I expect that on running the build command, a build folder is created containing all the optimized version files of my projects because this is what is required to be uploaded to my FTP account for hosting

I think the first response here can help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598274/why-there-is-no-physical-client-build-folder-when-i-run-nodejs-server-with-react

You can refer to this section.
In my understanding, .next directory includes optimized files for deploying, but only the files in .next directory can't run your nextjs application. As mentioned in the link above, it depends on environment that you choose.
